# Require code from github in composer.json throwing TransportException

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I forked a project into my own repo, made an update, and am trying to require it into another PHP project with composer.json.

I added a require block for my (public) repo:

```
"repositories":  [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "name": "geoff-maddock/laravel-calendar",
        "url": "https://github.com/geoff-maddock/laravel-calendar"
    }
  ],
```

And then I require the code in the require block:

```
    "geoff-maddock/laravel-fullcalendar": "^1.3.4",
```

However, when I run composer update, I get an error such as:

gmaddock@Wrecked:/var/www/dev-events$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                 
  The "https://api.github.com/repos/geoff-maddock/laravel-calendar" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

I couldn't find anything on this specific error.  I'm not sure why it translates my URL into api, as if you hit that URL directly, it won't work.   Any suggestions on what might be happening?

The composer.json code is:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories":  [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "name": "geoff-maddock/laravel-calendar",
            "url": "https://github.com/geoff-maddock/laravel-calendar"
        }
      ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "~5.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "suin/php-rss-writer": "^1.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "sentry/sentry": "^2.3",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^1.8",
        "alt-three/bus": "^4.0",
        "laravel-notification-channels/twitter": "^5.1",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1",
        "eluceo/ical": "^0.16.0",
        "geoff-maddock/laravel-fullcalendar": "^1.3.4",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5.3",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^2.6",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1"
    },
 },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~6.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.1",
        "laravel/dusk": "^6.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.8",
        "nunomaduro/larastan": "^0.6.9"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
                    "app/Http/helpers.php",
                    "app/Http/Flash.php"
                ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": ["tests/utilities/functions.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php-latest artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php-latest artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php-latest -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php-latest artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],
        "phpstan": [
            "./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse"
        ],
        "tests": [
            "./vendor/bin/phpunit"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up publishing this to packagist and was able to pull it in, but never got pulling from github working.